# Can a non-elevated process use the Windows Filtering Platform (WFP)?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, firewall, wfp

I cannot find any information on what kind of privileges a Windows process needs to be able to use WFP (Windows filtering platform). I assume it requires administrator privileges, as WFP allows a process to block packets in the whole system, and also to interfere with network traffic of other processes. Is this correct? Or can a non-elevated process also use WFP?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/access-control